# Lowpass Filter in Frequency Domain

Tags: dns, frequency

I had a set of data and I plot it as in Figure 1[image]

Then I used the lowpass filter to remove noise as below

N = length(FM);

n = floor(0.005*N);

H = zeros(size(FM));

H(1:n) = 1;

H( (N/2+2):N ) = H(N/2:-1:2);

LP_FM = FM .* H;

lp_fm = ifft(LP_FM);

plot(timesec,fm);

hold on

plot(timesec,real(lp_fm),'Linewidth',2);

I got the results as in Figure 2

[image]

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here, please?

Why I got the abnormal values at the beginning?

Greatly appreciate for your help :)

Thanks!

Comment: Which software are you using: Matlab, R, Scilab, etc.?

Comment: I am using Matlab.